# Adding an object to an array only if that object does not already exist in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to make an inventory system where when an item is obtained it will only put the item into the array if it does not already exist in the array. Then regardless of whether it was put into the array or not, find the item in the array and increase its amount by 1. This is what I have at the moment:

```
function newItem(){
    apple = new uniqueItem("apple", "resources/apple.png")

    if (inventory.indexOf(apple) != null){
        inventory.push(apple)
    }
    inventory[inventory.indexOf(apple)].amount += 1
}
```

Im still pretty new to javascript and I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction

Comment: `indexOf(object)` ? I guess you should deal with the keys of the object..

Comment: `var arr=[{a:10},{b:20}]; var a={a:10}; arr.indexOf(a);` will be `-1`

Comment: ah ok, but just out of interest would something like     'arr.indexOf({name:"apple", imgLink:"resources/apple.png"})' work?

Comment: 2 objects can be equal if all the keys and values of the object are equal..And that is why you need to iterate and compare..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use indexOf here. Use something like below which iterates over the array and compares with each object in it. indexOf takes a string as value rather than a object.

```
function containsObject(obj, list) {
   var i;
   for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { 
     if (list[i] === obj) { return true; } 
   } 
   return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is this `Array.prototype.includes()` method at your service just for this job.

```
var o1 = {a:1,b:2},
   arr = [];
arr.push(o1);
arr.includes(o1); // <- true so don't add again
```

For more on this check [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) out.

Comment: `var arr=[{a:10},{b:20}];` and `arr.includes({a:10});` is evaluated as `false`

Comment: @RayonDabre so do `arr.indexOf({a:10});` returns -1. Plus in my above example arr.indexOf(o1) would return 0 and this might yield false if you don't check properly like `~arr.indexOf(o1)`  which makes your code unreadable. Best is to implement `Array.prototype.includes()` since it's already there.

Comment: The reason is you are passing `reference` not the value..`Reference` can point to the same `object`

Comment: IE doesn't support includes function. you need latest chrome and firefox. Better go with indexOf or loop and match .

Comment: if you are using lodash you can check _.findIndex(array, [predicate=_.identity]) this function which will find index based on your property

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by your own! Just loop through all inventory and check whether the item you are trying to insert is already exist. If it doesn't exist then insert it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you too

```
    <p> Year : <select style="width: 150px;">
        <option value ="2014">2014</option>
        <option value ="2015">2015</option>
        <option value =" '2015">2015</option>

    </select>
    </p>

    <input  type="submit" value="Submit">
            <input type="submit" value="cancel">

</center>
</body>
```

Comment: Aaah! What ? How ?